# Understanding Softmax Probability

Tags: machine-learning, regression, softmax

Given the following Softmax regression model, what is the probability of this instance belonging to the class of Bare Soil?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, this is how you need to calculate the probability:

```
import numpy as np
d = {"vegetation": 0.3, "bare soil": 0.1, "impervious": 0.1}

P_baresoil = np.exp(d["bare soil"]) / np.sum(np.exp(list(d.values())))
P_vegetation = np.exp(d["vegetation"]) / np.sum(np.exp(list(d.values())))
P_impervious = np.exp(d["impervious"]) / np.sum(np.exp(list(d.values())))
```

P_baresoil = 0.31